# What is the best way for a .NET client application to connect to a WebSocket server?

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, client

I want to develop a Windows Desktop application (**.NET 4.5.2**) which should connect to a extern provided Server via WebSocket and consume events/notifications. The server pushes the data **JSON-coded** to the client.

Unfortually the SignalR client library only supports SignalR WebSockets.
I want to connect to a URI like this: `ws://servername:port/socket`.

What is the best library or a valid way to connect to such a server?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with ClientWebSocket library read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket?view=netframework-4.7.2)
it has support for.net 4.5,there is an example [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WebSockets-middle-tier-5b2972ce/view/SourceCode)